# How do I add a tag to a Github commit?

Tags: github, tagging

When making a GitHub commit, how do I tag it using the git command-line options before pushing it to remote repo?

Can something like this be done?
`git commit -m 'first commit' -tag -a v0.0.1 -m "1st release"`

Comment: Can't just run `git tag` before the `commit` command?

Comment: Create your commit, then tag it. Why do you want to do that in a single command?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot commit & tag in one command.

```
git commit -m "prepare for v1.0.0 release"
git tag v1.0.0
git push origin master --tags
```

All you can do is connect commands via `&&`:

```
git commit -m "prepare for v1.0.0 release" && git tag v1.0.0 && git push origin master --tags
```